# How update string on several files from command line?

Tags: bash, sed, gnu

I want to update a string on several text files from command line (bash).

Answer (score -1):

To update string to 'John' only script text files (*.sh) containing the searched string 'Peter' and make backup first (.bak):

**¡¡DON'T USE!!**

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/Peter/John/g' $(find bin/ -type f -name '*.sh' \-exec grep -l Peter {} +)
```

Thanks for your comments [Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel) and [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)

After research I found this solution (\b is for word limit if you only want to change words):

```
$ STRING_OLD="\bPeter\b"; STRING_NEW="John"; find bin/ -type f -name '*.sh' -not -name "*.bak" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Zl "$STRING_OLD" | xargs -t -0 sed -i.bak 's/'"$STRING_OLD"'/'"$STRING_NEW"'/g'
```

It works with filenames/directories with spaces,tabs,new lines and non ASCII chars.

Variable STRING_OLD is a regexp for sed s/regexp/replacement/ command. You must aware of it.

You also see changed files. It only changes (and backs up) in files where STRING_OLD is found in regexp. The rest of the files remain untouched (that's what I wanted).

Comment: That breaks if the file/directory name contains spaces/tabs and new lines....

Comment: ... or if the search string contains regexp metachars or a string that can be a substring of another, or the replacement string contains backreference metachars...